# Difference between 日{に}本{ほん} and 来{らい}日{にち}

Tags: word-choice, meaning

What is the difference between `日{に}本{ほん}` and `来{らい}日{にち}`? Both of them means `Japan` right?
I  understand that `来{らい}` means `next`, like `来{らい}年{ねん}`. But above context is interesting to me.

Comment: Did you look up 来日 in a dictionary and find "Japan" as a definition?  What dictionary?

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis Google Translate is incredibly inaccurate, don't use it for looking up words (or anything at all, actually).

Comment: Since it was Google Translate error, I have changed my question. I think we should delete the comments above. And thanks for help indeed.

Comment: Hello!  There is no need to delete your question or edit it.  It has already been answered, and we shouldn't change questions in ways that would invalidate existing answers.  If you would like to ask something else, please feel free to ask a new question!

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis leave the question as it. If you'd like to ask a new question, make a new question.

Comment: OK..., but it will be down-voted 100 times.. :)

Comment: I don't think anyone here is motivated to pile downvotes on (consider it's at -1 and 3 of us have commented). The question is still pedagogical due how it highlights why Google Translate cannot do English <-> Japanese.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

「日本」 means "Japan".

「来日」 means a "visit to Japan" said from the Japan side.  "A visit to Japan" said from the visitor's country side, it is 「[訪日]{ほうにち}」.

Here, 「来」 means "to come", not "next".